# Driveway Water Pipe Cover

Tags: water, concrete, pipe

I've recently had my driveway replaced, and one thing that didn't come out very nicely is this water pipe/main thing. I'm not sure exactly what it is, so any additional information would be welcome.

Anyway, they pulled it up as far as it would go when they re-poured the driveway, but still after the new driveway was poured, its now below the grade of the driveway.

The result is that water accumulates here and freezes and rusts the metal in there. This also just generally looks terrible.

Am I allowed to put concrete over this or finish it somehow? What can I do to cover this or finish it in any way?

Since the driveway is already poured, I can't use a cleanout plug or anything.

[image: driveway water tap/main]

Here's another picture of something I see all over the neighborhood on the sidewalks. What is it? Is it the same thing where it was a water main that was covered over with concrete? Is this something I can do to the water thing on my driveway?

[image: mystery covered sidewalk thing]

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Planning that before starting is the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

That's the shutoff valve for the water supply for your house. You should also have another main water shutoff valve in your home probably in the basement or a utility room. If you ever need to replace the main shutoff in your home, you or your water company will need to turn off the water at the street by removing that cap and using a long-handled curb-key to reach the valve.
So, no, you can't just cover it over. You really should have discussed this with the paving company when they bid the job.
I would suggest that you contact your water supplier. They should be able to advise you on possible solutions. They may have a short extension that would at least raise it to surface level. If so, you should then contact your paving company to have them come back out to do a professional patch around the plate. They have some culpability in this as well.